# AJAX jsf для h:commandButton

Tags: ajax, jsf

priceList.xhtml
я попытался прикрутить ajax такой конструкцией, но все равно страница при нажатии кнопки удаления перезагружается.

```
<h:commandButton id="ajax" action="#{priceBean.deletePriceRecord(price.id)}" value="Delete" class="">
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="column"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

render="column", пробовал так же подставлять id PriceTable но тоже не работает.

вот сама страница

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
>

<h:head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Conpatible"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <title>JSF CRUD Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tableUpdated {
            width: 90% !important;
            margin: 17px 58px 0 !important;
        }

        .btnSpace {
            margin: 17px;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2><h:outputText value="Prices for Cars"/></h2>
    <h:form id="PriceForm">
        <h:dataTable id="PriceTable" binding="#{table}" value="#{priceBean.pricesList()}" var="price"
                     class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered tableUpdated">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{price.id}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{price.name}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{price.value}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
                <h:commandButton action="#{priceBean.editPriceRecord(price.id)}" value="Edit"
                                 class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </h:column>


            <h:column id = "column">
                <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                <h:commandButton id="ajax" action="#{priceBean.deletePriceRecord(price.id)}" value="Delete" class="">
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="column"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>


        </h:dataTable>

        <h:commandButton action="createPrice.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" value="Create New Price"
                         class="btn btn-success btnSpace"/>
        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton action="/pages/index.jsp?faces-redirect=true" value="На страницу авторизации"
                             class="btn btn-success btnSpace"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком вызове `<f:ajax execute="@this" render="column"/>` не происходит повторное чтение всего списка с бина `value="#{priceBean.pricesList()}"`, в копии списка компонента `h:dataTable` это поле не удалено. Для повторного считывания данных с бина нужно обновить вышестоящий компонент, например форму. Также `action` выполняет навигацию если метод возвращает строковое значение адреса страницы, в противном случаи обновляет текущую страницу. `id` текущей формы можно получить через сокращение `@form`. Следующий код возможно исправит проблему

```
<h:commandButton id="ajax" actionListener="#{priceBean.deletePriceRecord(price.id)}" value="Delete" class="">
     <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@from"/>
</h:commandButton>
```